# How to arrange Buttons in Circular shape in wpf using c# code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and want to arrange several buttons dynamically in circular shape.can use any of the panel(currently using Canvas).

Comment: this is not a Learn playground forum, so you need to tell what you try so far and we will help to correct you. But to answer your question, use a Circular formula set button's top and left position and it will solve it :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a c# code may this Helps you

```
Point cntr = new Point(this.Width/2, this.Height/2); // cntr Points Center of Circle
// Count gives Number of Buttons        
int count = 25; 
// angle gives angle Between each Button
double angle = 360/(double)count; 
int radius = 150; // Circle's Radius
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "Button " + i;
    button.Location = new Point((int)(cntr.X + radius * Math.Cos((angle * i) * Math.PI / 180)),
        (int)(cntr.Y + radius * Math.Sin((angle * i) * Math.PI / 180)));
    this.Panle1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: why down vote if i could help him so what's wrong in it

Comment: Thanks Aden its very helpful n innovative.